# Get row id on button click

Tags: c#, jquery, webforms

I need to get a row id from database with the button click.

This is my c# code:

```
protected void ddlBC_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LogicTableAdapters.getLvLKarTableAdapter getKar = new LogicTableAdapters.getLvLKarTableAdapter();

    DataTable dtKar = getKar.getLvLKar(ddlBC.SelectedValue);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[2]
    { 
        new DataColumn("CharName", typeof(string)),                
        new DataColumn("LevelID", typeof(int))
    });

    foreach (DataRow dr in dtKar.Rows)
    {                     
        dt.Rows.Add(dr["CharName"].ToString(), dr["LevelID"].ToString());
    }

    gvKar.DataSource = dt;
    gvKar.DataBind();
}

protected void btnButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

This is dynamically GridView that gets populated by the procedure when item in ddl is selected:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvKar" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="LevelID" OnRowDataBound="gvKarakteristike_RowDataBound">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Kar">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Kar" runat="server" Width="150px" Height="30px" Font-Names="Georgia" MyCustomAttr="foo" margin-Left="100px" Text='<%# Bind("CharName") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:Button ID="btnButton" runat="server" Text="Show"  autopostback="True"/>
```

When the button is clicked in form of alert row id from every row must be shown from database.

Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: Why jquery tag ?

Comment: Maybe jquery can help somehow in displaying rows id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use code like this to assign a click handler to the row:

```
Protected Sub Grid_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)

    'apply click attribute to select a row 
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        e.Row.Attributes("onclick") = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(sender, "Select$" & e.Row.RowIndex)
    End If

End Sub
```

Then this to get the relevant data from the datakeys collection

```
Protected Sub Grid_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As GridViewCommandEventArgs)

    If e.CommandName = "Select" Then
        Dim LevelID As String = GridResults.DataKeys(e.CommandArgument).Item("LevelID")
        ' Do something with ID here
    End If

End Sub
```